# How can I encrypt and decrypt PDF with PHP?

Tags: php, file, pdf, encryption

I need to encrypt and decrypt (using a secret key) documents (namely pdf). Is there any snipet in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: http://www.codediesel.com/php/encrypting-uploaded-files-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a [GnuPG module](http://php.net/gnupg) you can use.

Comment: I do not have a dedicated server, so I can not use it